# Non-recursive git log and diff

Tags: git, depth, git-diff, git-log, non-recursive

```
git log -p .
```

only within the current directory but not in subdirectories

equivalent

```
svn log --diff --depth files .
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
$ git log -p file1 file2 ...
```

Or, if they're too many to type:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs git log -p
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but list of existing files is not enough, the problem is I want to look deleted files also

Comment: I'm afraid there's no support for that sort of operation in git. If you really want something like that, you're going to have to hack together a helper to list current and former elements of your directory.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux or the like you can list only the files in the current directory with:

```
ls -p | grep -v /
```

so:

```
git log -p `ls -p | grep -v /`
```

is one way to do it.

Comment: the file list can not be generated from the current working area. a normal git log behavior would evaluate the path against the version even when the path doesn't exist in the working area

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work:

```
git log --all --pretty=format: --name-only --relative="$(git rev-parse --show-prefix)" -- . | sed '/\//d ; /^[[:space:]]*$/d' | sort | uniq | xargs git log -p --
```

- The first git command lists every single file ever, including deleted ones. Each file will be listed once for each time it was changed. The `--relative` will remove files not from this directory and also remove the subdirectory prefix from the file names.
- Sed removes the ones not in the current directory (i.e. that don't contain a slash). This works because we removed the subdir prefix in the previous step. It also removes the empty lines.
- Sort and uniq remove the duplicates.
- Now we have the list of files we're interested in, xargs will pass them to `git log -p`. The `--` is needed otherwise it won't know what to do with the deleted files.

It seems like an inefficient way of completing the task but I don't think git has the concept of "every file", it just has the current set of files and a list of diffs. So you have to go through every change set to get the complete list.